# No connection could be made error in phpThumb()

Tags: phpthumb

I'm using phpThunmb to display images from external link. for some images, such type of error occurred as below.

[image]

i tried to get the header information of that image as below..

```
 $headers = get_headers($external_image_url);
```

but the result was empty. how to solve this error? if this image can not be accessed then how to display an alternate "image imageNotFound.jpg" in it's place .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code to check if the given image exists or not.

```
if(file_exists($external_image_url)) 
{
  $image_link = $external_image_url; //if that image exists
 }
 else
    {
      $image_link = "imageNotFount.jpg"; //if that image does not exists
    }
```